# Using `includes` instead of `joins` and using sql `SUM` method to avoid N+1

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got some old legacy code to which I've added additional parameters (i've removed unnecessary parts):

```
Farm.joins("LEFT JOIN ( SELECT farm_id, SUM(kwota) as suma_wplat FROM payments GROUP BY farm_id) as kwoty ON kwoty.farm_id = farms.id").
      select("farms.id, kwoty.suma_wplat").includes(:certificate).where("certificates.data_wyslania IS null")
```

That will produce such query:

```
"SELECT farms.id, kwoty.suma_wplat FROM `farms` LEFT JOIN ( SELECT farm_id, SUM(kwota) as suma_wplat FROM payments GROUP BY farm_id) as kwoty ON kwoty.farm_id = farms.id WHERE (certificates.data_wyslania IS null)"
```

Unfortunately that will fail as `suma_wplat` is not available later (returned objects consist of all `Farm` attributes).

If I'll change `includes` to `joins` produced query will look like that:

```
 "SELECT farms.id, kwoty.suma_wplat FROM `farms` INNER JOIN `certificates` ON `certificates`.`farm_id` = `farms`.`id` AND `certificates`.`year` = '2013' LEFT JOIN ( SELECT farm_id, SUM(kwota) as suma_wplat FROM payments GROUP BY farm_id) as kwoty ON kwoty.farm_id = farms.id WHERE (certificates.data_wyslania IS null)"
```

and now `Farm` consists of proper fields (together with counted sum `suma_wplat`) but it results in N+1 queries.

How can I resolve that? For now I can only think about adding another column to `Farm` with counted value, but that w'd be a workaround, not true solution.

Edit: Whole query looks now like this:

```
Farm.joins("LEFT JOIN ( SELECT farm_id, SUM(kwota) as suma_wplat FROM payments GROUP BY farm_id) as kwoty ON kwoty.farm_id = farms.id").select("farms.id, kwoty.suma_wplat").map do |f|
  (...)
  f.suma_wplat
end
```

Comment: I would think that query would actually fail because certificates is not referenced in the FROM clause

Comment: What code produces the N queries?

Comment: Thanks for response, N+1 is produced by code with `joins` (last one).

Comment: That's one query though. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, I haven't added  it to the post, later `map` is being called on results, I don't have now access to that code so I will update it later.